# Changing background-image property to a local image file using Safari Extension

Tags: safari-extension

(MacBook Pro Mid 2015 / OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 / Safari 8.0.8)

I want to change `background-image` of a particular webpage.
I made a Safari Extension and make such a css file as `style.css`

```
body { background-image: url('background.png'); }
```

I also put `background.png` to the same directory with `style.css`
And Safari Developer license is already set.

Then, in Extension Builder, I set some properties as follows:

- Extension Website Access: `All`
- Injected Extension Content:

  - Style Sheets: `style.css`
- Whitelist: `http://__mywebsite__.com/*`

Although I installed this, background of my webpage didn't seem to be enabled.

I think the solution must be these:

- Safari Extension can't find a local file `background.png`
- I set wrong whitelist pattern
- I set wrong parameter to Extension Website Access

What should I do? Any comments would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you link to an image on a web page, does it work? try putting this link in and see if it works: http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff 
If it does then the problem is with the directory or one of the other things you mentioned

Comment: I set `body { background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff') !important; }` but anything changed, And I also tried `body { display: hidden !important; }` but nothing happened

Comment: Are any styles working? Is there an issue with the style tag you are using? Have you tried inline css? <body style="background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff') !important; "></body>

Comment: I tried following: `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400')";` and set 'script.js' to "Injected Extension Content - End Scripts:" but nothing happened. And I also tried `console.log("test");` but result was same ;^(